# Sidebar always minified

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinydashboardplus

I know that shinydashboardPlus allows me to minified the sidebar like the example:

```
siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 50,
    collapsed = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu(
        id = 'sidebar', # Tab1
        menuItem("Tab number One", tabName = 'tab1', 
                 icon = shiny::icon('chart-area')
        ), # Tab2
        menuItem("Tab number Two", tabName = 'tab2',
                 icon = shiny::icon('map')
        )
    )
)
```

What I can't find is a code that shows the sidebar always minified. I want only a sidebar with only the icons and the full information showing up only when hovering with the mouse.

I don't have a reproductive example, but I have some images to better clarify my question.

I cant have this kind of sidebar [1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6QMN.png

Only this kind [2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJuBV.png

I tried to remove the "hamburguer" icon so the client can't maximize the bar, but it makes the dash unusable in small screens.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. What is meant by " I don't want a full sidebar the side of a minified one, either". Also, add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clarify how the expected output shall look like.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried to better clarify the question.